# Create perspective of rectangles lying on a flat surface

Tags: iphone, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I have been working in objective-c for a while now, but I haven't really had a need (until now) to dive deeper into core animation and graphic manipulation.

I currently have four UIImageViews that I want to animate into a position that makes them look like they are lying down on a flat surface.  What I mean by that is that they will start as rectangles - undistorted and flat on the screen, but will animate into the skewed perspective that makes it look like they are sitting on a flat surface.

I believe that CATransform3D is what I need to do and have read a number of docs that all point to using .m34 to create the correct perspective.  I just can't seem to get it to work.  Below is a snippet of code that I am using just to try and get the image to skew.  When I use the code below, just to try and skew the image, it seems to cut it off instead of showing the right perspective.

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity; 
transform.m34 = -1.0f / 700.0f;
// Perform other transforms
transform = CATransform3DRotate( transform,
    degreesToRadians(45.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

[layer setTransform:transform];
```

I can handle the animations fine, but am having trouble getting the final image skewed so that it looks correct.  Anyone have any suggestions or samples on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The animation looks skewed to me. Try experimenting with the m34 factor to make it skew more (setting it to a lower value like -1.0f/200.0f). Just experiment and you will eventually get it right. You can change to rotation to something else than 45 degrees if you want it to skew more.

If your transform doesn't skew at all then maybe one of your other transforms are overwriting the transform (I.e you are using one of the Make transform calls). If so: try moving the transform.m34 assignment to be the last thing before applying the transform.